# Carrying information from one shapefile to another based on location using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, combine

I am a R user but I couldn't do this on R and decided it might be easier on ArcMap but I don't know how to use it that well.

I have two shapefiles for same county, one of them has 360 features but attached to a long distance of a road, other one 7345 features but short roads. Example; let's say there is a major artery speed limit range 30-55 in 10 miles. So they separated this road 25 pieces in one shapefile, other one has the volume of road for 10 miles there is only one feature.

```
Line1
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 7162 
extent      : -84.70612, -83.98041, 30.27399, 30.68428  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 52

Line2
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 376 
extent      : 143516.4, 213981, 3353367, 3399153  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 22


LineMerged
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 7538
extent      : 143511.3, 214019.4, 3353367, 3399153  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 75
```

I want to combine these two files, they have different proj4.

I merged them on ArcMap, I have 7538 features and uses Line2. but volume is only available 376 location when I read it on R.

Is there a way carry information on Line2 to Line1 since it has more features and speed changes on a lot of locations but volume is same. if i can add volume in that location, would be amazing.

[Getting information from one shapefile to another using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42946) is not helping me.

Comment: Look at spatial join tool?

Comment: I tried that and it gives the columns but shows as zero. Join data-> each line will be given all the attributes.

Comment: reproject both layers in the same CRS before doing the spatial join

Comment: @LéoM how can I do that?

Comment: ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Projections and Transformations > Project

Comment: I managed to convert them and when I combined volume column show up as zero. I wouldn't mind to provide the shapefiles if there is a way to upload it.

Comment: Could you please define "volume of road"?

Comment: The volume of the road is a feature that shows the number of cars passes on that road. I believe when you driving you see black lines on the road, that's how they count the number of cars on that specific road.

Answer (score 0):

As @LeoM says in the comments, [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) one layer first, then you can [Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) the two files. You might want to also look into [Dynamic Segmentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/dynamic-segmentation.htm) as a cleaner way to store speed limit data then breaking the road into a bunch of separate line features.